# How to stop excel changing format of cell from 'text' to 'custom' (mmm-yy) when I edit entry

Tags: excel, type-conversion, format

I am using MS Excel. I have a text cell containing the string 'C1_05-4422'. I make sure it is formatted as a 'text' using the format cells menu. I then use the replace command to replace '*_' in 'C1_05-4422' with '' (null). Instead of the desired text '05-4422' Excel changes the entry to 01/05/4421 (displayed as 'May-21') and also changes the cell format from 'text' to 'Custom' (mmm-yy).

I want to do this with a lot of cells. I am preparing data to be read into another program and so I do not want to add special characters, blank spaces, quotation marks, equal signs, etc. I just want to be able to edit the text-formatted C1_05-4422 to 05-4422 and similar changes in a large number of entries and for the specified format 'text' to persist without conversion to a date.

Tried to save as .csv file, .txt file (tab separated) and .xlsx file, but that did not help. I tried to remove conversions from preferences, but that did not help. I tried switching format back to 'text' after conversion but it converts date to an integer.

Running on Macbook Air (M2), Excel 16.81 (Microsoft 365)

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTITUTE(B2, LEFT(B2, FIND("_", B2)), "")

Give a try to the above formula, it convert successfully to 05-4422 and not to date